# Voltage Selector Circuit

Tags: mosfet

I'm trying to design a circuit that essentially will allow you to select which voltage will be used by a number of electronics on the board (VccISO in the schematic). The voltages are already being regulated elsewhere, so it's just a matter of picking from thme. I'm expecting a current of up to 1A on VCCiso. Originally I had hoped I could do this directly with a DIP switch, but the ones that fit my application can only handle 100mA.

[image]

So I tried instead to have a DIP switch control this indirectly using MOSFETs. The gate of one of the N channel MOSEFET goes high, which pulls the respective P channel MOSFET low and turns it ON.

However the issue I have since realized is that the given the body diode of a P channel MOSFET, as VCCiso raises higher and higher you quickly have an unusable circuit.

[image]

Does anyone have some suggestions for a different approach?

Comment: Placing high current schottky diodes in series with each PMOS *(i.e. for each diode, anode to the respective drain and cathode to VccISO - just like a Diode-OR)* can be a simple solution. Note that you should expect 0.3-0.5VDC drop at 1A. *I'm on mobile, I can't draw a schematic, sorry. I hope I could describe.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RK makes a good point.  But if you really want to stay with MOSFETs, then

1. Eliminate all of the n-channel parts, change the SW1 pole connection switch the FET gates directly to GND.
2. Replace each p-channel FETs with two FETs in series.  Gates tied together to the switch, sources tied together and to the gate resistor, and one drain to the Vccxxx and one drain to Vcciso

If you look at Linear Technology hot-swap and electronic circuit breaker controller chips, you will see this back-to-back FET approach as a common solution to the diode problem.

Comment: Just to add. They also use this approach of back to back MOSFETs for load switch applications for multiplexing  power supplies to one load. There are ICs with dual PMOSFETs that have source pins connected internally. But there are ones with dual PMOSFETs with all pins unconnected. For example, Si4963BDY, is such part.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! So the one MOSFET basically acts like a schottky diode block but when it turns ON it avoids the voltage drop of an actual schottky diode. So handy!

Answer (score 1):

Go old school.   Replace the PMOS with PNP bipolar transistors.  You'll lose a little efficiency, but you'll not have the body-diode problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a DIP switch, you could use a 2x4 post header and a shunt/jumper,like so:
[image]